# how to convert this time 2007-10-01T01:02:03.004 into datetime in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

2007-10-01T01:02:03.004 convert into datetime in snowflake

i used yyyymmddhh24miss

2022-11-03 09:13:48.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of input time format is automatically recognized. The following should work:

```
select to_timestamp_ntz('2007-10-01T01:02:03.004');
```

the output will depend on the output data format set as a session parameter, e.g.:

```
alter session set timestamp_ntz_output_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3';
```

Therefore the select statement above will output:

> 2007-10-01 01:02:03.004

[doc refference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html)

To manipulate the actual timestamp value, you can use the DATEADD() function, e.g.:

```
select dateadd(months, 175, to_timestamp_ntz('2007-10-01T01:02:03.004')) as result;
```

Output:

> 2022-05-01 01:02:03.004

[Doc refference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html)